# Which banks / companies offer virtual or instant credit card services in the UK?

Tags: credit-card, united-kingdom, security, virtual-credit-card

I'm looking to make a small number of hotel and guest-house reservations, and thought that generated credit card numbers with defined limits would be a good idea.

Which companies provide such services in the UK, either as an additional service to a regular credit card, or as a stand-alone service?

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be no Virtual Credit Card issuers in UK. There is a Virtual Debit Card / or more like Pre-Paid Card available. The free look quite steep. More at
http://www.creditsolveuk.com/virtual-prepaid-mastercard-credit-card.htm

If safety of online transactions is a concern then using an additional verification provided by Barclays card may help. For more details
http://www.barclaycard.co.uk/personal-home/cards/barclaycard-secure-demo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Monzo now [offers this service](https://monzo.com/help/monzo-plus/virtual-cards-how), but only if you subscribe to the paid Monzo Plus account.